# Copy body and headers from hyper HTTP request to a new request while inspecting the body

Tags: rust, hyper

I would like to create a small Rust HTTP proxy using hyper which accepts requests, forwards them and dumps the request + body.

Based on [this example](https://gist.github.com/meganehouser/d5e1b47eb2873797ebdc440b0ed482df), the proxy part works fine.

However, I can't simply copy & print the request body. My main problem is that the request body can't be simply copied into something like an `Vec<u8>`. I cannot `deconstruct` the request to read the body and then create it later since the deconstructed headers can't be added to a new request.

The following code shows my minimal HTTP proxy example:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate hyper;
extern crate tokio_core;

use futures::{Future, Stream};

use hyper::{Body, Client, StatusCode};
use hyper::client::HttpConnector;
use hyper::header::{ContentLength, ContentType};
use hyper::server::{Http, Request, Response, Service};

use tokio_core::reactor::Core;

type HTTPClient = Client<HttpConnector, Body>;

struct Server {
    client: HTTPClient,
}

impl Server {
    pub fn new(client: HTTPClient) -> Server {
        Server { client: client }
    }
}

impl Service for Server {
    type Request = Request;
    type Response = Response;
    type Error = hyper::Error;
    type Future = Box<Future<Item = Self::Response, Error = Self::Error>>;

    fn call(&self, mut req: Request) -> Self::Future {
        let req_uri_str = {
            let uri = req.uri();
            format!(
                "http://localhost{}?{}",
                uri.path(),
                uri.query().unwrap_or_default()
            )
        };
        req.set_uri(req_uri_str.parse().unwrap());

        // Try to create a copy of the new request
        /*
        let (method, uri, version, headers, body) = req.deconstruct();
        let mut req_copy: Request<hyper::Body> = Request::new(method, uri);

        // Main problem: How can the request body be copied?
        // >>> let body_bytes: Vec<u8> = ...

        req_copy.set_body(body);
        req_copy.set_version(version);

        // Try to copy the headers
        for header in headers.iter() {
            req_copy.headers_mut().set(header.value().unwrap());
        }
        */

        // This works if the request is not deconstructed
        let work = self.client
            .request(req)
            .and_then(|res| futures::future::ok(res))
            .or_else(|err| {
                let body = format!("{}\n", err);
                futures::future::ok(
                    Response::new()
                        .with_status(StatusCode::BadRequest)
                        .with_header(ContentType::plaintext())
                        .with_header(ContentLength(body.len() as u64))
                        .with_body(body),
                )
            });

        Box::new(work)
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Create HTTP client core + handles
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();
    let handle_clone = handle.clone();

    // Create HTTP server
    let server_addr = "127.0.0.1:9999".parse().unwrap();
    let server = Http::new()
        .serve_addr_handle(&server_addr, &handle, move || {
            Ok(Server::new(Client::new(&handle_clone)))
        })
        .unwrap();

    // Connect HTTP client with server
    let handle_clone2 = handle.clone();
    handle.spawn(
        server
            .for_each(move |conn| {
                handle_clone2.spawn(conn.map(|_| ()).map_err(|err| println!("Error: {:?}", err)));
                Ok(())
            })
            .map_err(|_| ()),
    );

    core.run(futures::future::empty::<(), ()>()).unwrap();
}
```

Running this works fine, if you have any HTTP service running on Port 80, connecting with a browser to port 9999 will forward any responses and requests perfectly.

However, if you re-enable the lines regarding the construction of a new, copied request, my approach fails since I don't understand how to copy the headers. (Furthermore, this doesn't really help me when it comes to copying the request body)

I'm aware that there are similar questions here, but none of them match my requirement to re-use the request body after looking at it (or don't have answers at all).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the request body can't be simply copied into something like an `Vec<u8>`

Sure it can. In the Rust standard library, it's worth memorizing the capabilities of the `Iterator` trait. When dealing with futures, you should also memorize the capabilities of [`Future`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/futures/future/trait.Future.html) and [`Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html).

For example, hyper's [`Body`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.11.22/hyper/struct.Body.html) implements `Stream`. This means you can use the [`Stream::concat2`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.concat2) method:

> Concatenate all results of a stream into a single extendable destination, returning a future representing the end result.

This creates one large `Chunk` which can be converted to a `Vec`:

```
extern crate hyper; // 0.11.22
extern crate futures; // 0.1.18

use futures::{Future, Stream};

fn example(req: hyper::Request) {
    req.body().concat2().map(|chunk| {
        let body = chunk.to_vec(); 
        println!("{:?}", body);
        ()
    });
    // Use this future somehow!
}
```

Likewise, a `Vec<u8>` can be converted back into a `Body`.

> since the deconstructed headers can't be added to a new request.

```
req_copy.headers_mut().extend(headers.iter());
```

---

All together:

```
fn create_localhost_request(req: Request) -> (Request, Body) {
    let (method, uri, version, headers, body) = req.deconstruct();

    let req_uri_str = {
        format!(
            "http://localhost{}?{}",
            uri.path(),
            uri.query().unwrap_or_default()
        )
    };
    let uri = req_uri_str.parse().unwrap();

    let mut req_copy = Request::new(method, uri);
    req_copy.set_version(version);
    req_copy.headers_mut().extend(headers.iter());

    (req_copy, body)
}

fn perform_proxy_request(
    client: HttpClient,
    req: Request,
) -> Box<Future<Item = Response, Error = hyper::Error>> {
    Box::new(client.request(req).or_else(|err| {
        let body = format!("{}\n", err);
        Ok(Response::new()
            .with_status(StatusCode::BadRequest)
            .with_header(ContentType::plaintext())
            .with_header(ContentLength(body.len() as u64))
            .with_body(body))
    }))
}

impl Service for Server {
    type Request = Request;
    type Response = Response;
    type Error = hyper::Error;
    type Future = Box<Future<Item = Self::Response, Error = Self::Error>>;

    fn call(&self, req: Request) -> Self::Future {
        let (mut req, body) = create_localhost_request(req);
        let client = self.client.clone();

        let work = body
            .concat2()
            .map(|chunk| chunk.to_vec())
            // Do whatever we need with the body here, but be careful
            // about doing any synchronous work.
            .map(move |body| {
                req.set_body(body);
                req
            })
            .and_then(|req| perform_proxy_request(client, req));

        Box::new(work)
    }
}
```

Comment: I must admit, I should have thought of simply working with the request body using the ``Iterator`` capabilities (I have seen ``concat2`` in the examples). Thank you very much, this is just what I wanted!

Comment: @PhilippLudwig `concat2` is not provided by `Iterator`; it's provided by `Stream`. There's a link to the appropriate docs above.

Comment: I see. Thanks to your detailed explanation, I also managed to inspect the response easily. I will have to read up on Streams and Futures though.

Comment: Is there a reason this code bit never made it into a `clone` trait on the request object?

Comment: @adv I don't know if any hyper maintainers ever saw this, or if anyone ever submitted a pull request to add it. Perhaps you can!

Comment: I may do that after we finish this project.  Not having `clone` on the request object has made this project 10x harder than it needed to be.  I will definitely look at PRing the copy method.  Thanks.

Comment: This answer doesn't work in new versions of `hyper` - there is no `deconstruct` anymore

Comment: @Qrilka it's called [`into_parts`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.13/hyper/struct.Request.html#method.into_parts) now.

Comment: Yeah, I found it but forgot to mention it here

Comment: This didn't work for me, as the `deconstruct()` method no longer exists -- and the mentioned `into_parts` has a different output type. This worked for me though: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-copy-http-request/43690/9